# How to pgrep over ssh, or use pgrep as a larger bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, grep

I'd like to run pgrep to find the ID of some process. It works great, except when run as a larger bash command as pgrep will also match it's parent shell/bash process which includes the match expression as part of it command-line.

pgrep sensibly excludes it own PID from the results, but less sensibly, doesn't seem to have an option to exclude its parent process(es).

Anyone come across this and have a good workaround.

Update.

```
pgrep -lf java || true
```

works fine, but

```
bash -c "(pgrep -lf java || true)"
echo 'bash -c "(pgrep -lf java || true)"' | ssh <host>
```

also identify the parent bash process.

I'm using pgrep as part of a much larger system, which it why the extra madness.

Comment: What system you are you using?  When I tried running `ssh <host> pgrep -lf bash` logging into a centos 6 system the pgrep did not show up in the output

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific command(s) that you are running.

Comment: Done. Have updated the question since this seems to be more about bash than ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue using python's `os.system(command)` which executes the command in a subshell.

`pgrep` does not match itself, but it does match it's parent shell which includes pgrep's arguments.

I found a solution:

```
pgrep -f the-arguments-here[^\[]
```

The `[^\[]` regex assures that it does not match the `[` (the beginning of the regex itself) and thus excludes the parent shell.

---

Example:

```
$ sh -c "pgrep -af the-arguments-here"

12345 actual-process with the-arguments-here
23456 sh -c pgrep -af the-arguments-here
```

vs:

```
$ sh -c "pgrep -af the-arguments-here[^\[]"

12345 actual-process with the-arguments-here
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not seeing why you need the bash -c see part.  You should be able to do

```
ssh <host> pgrep -lf java || true
```

which would actually run `true` on the local machine, but you could do

```
sssh <host> "pgrep -lf java || true"
```

if you needed true to be on the remote side.  Again, assuming your shell accepts that syntax (i.e., is bash)

You're already running everything on the other side of the ssh in a bash shell, so I don't think you need to explicitly invoke bash again--unless your default shell is something else then you may want to consider either changing that or scripting in the appropriate default shell.